# How can I pass non String parameters with HttpPost?

Tags: android, http-post

I use BasicNameValuePair class for passing String parameters with HttpPost in my Android application. How can I pass non String parameters like Double, Byte Array etc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer:
You can't. Not really.

Long answer:
The stuff that can be easily converted to a string you can just convert to a string (.toString) and parse (Double.parseStr()).

Common practice for byte arrays is to encode them in - for instance - Base64. [Android docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

Answer (score 1):

Convert them to strings?

```
String.valueOf();
```

Answer (score 0):

parse it as a string

```
whateverparameter.toString()
```

Comment: there's no way to pass byte array directly

Comment: for byte array I think the best way is to do new String(thebytearray);

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the value to `String`:

```
final Double myDouble = new Double("12.35");
new BasicNameValuePair(MY_DOUBLE_PARAM, myDouble.toString());
```